# Alert when the car hits the track in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```js
var car;
var front;
var back;
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transportation-2-4/60/transportation-2-flat-036-racing-car-top-512.png';

function startGame() {
  car = new move(12, 20, "red", 600, 300);
  pg.start();
}

var pg = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 1200;
    this.canvas.height = 600;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateframe, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      pg.keys = (pg.keys || []);
      pg.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      pg.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
  },
  stop: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function move(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

  this.type = type;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speed = 0;
  this.angle = 0;
  this.moveAngle = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
        ctx = pg.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
  ctx.drawImage(img, this.width / -2, this.height / -2,20,40); 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.width / -2, this.height / -2);
  ctx.lineTo(this.width / -2, 30);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.width / -2, 30);
  ctx.lineTo(13, (this.height / -2)+40);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(14, (this.height / -2)+40);
  ctx.lineTo(14, this.height / -2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(14, this.height / -2);
  ctx.lineTo(this.width / -2, this.height / -2);
  ctx.stroke();  
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(600, 800);
  ctx.stroke();

  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
    this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
    this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);

  }
}

function updateframe() {
  pg.clear();
  car.moveAngle = 0;
  car.speed = 0;
  if (pg.keys && pg.keys[37]) {
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {
      car.moveAngle = 5;
    }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]) {
      car.moveAngle = -5;
    }
  }
  if (pg.keys && pg.keys[39]) {
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {
      car.moveAngle = -5;
    }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]) {
      car.moveAngle = 5;
    }
  }
  if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]) {
    car.speed = 5;
  }
  if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {
    car.speed = -5;
  }
  car.newPos();
  car.update();
}

startGame();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

There is a car and a line, now i want to make an alert whenever the car get touched by the the line.

I know how to do this logically. like if i convert the car image in four lines (border) then use line intersection formula to get if there is  a intersection but i am new to this canvas drawing and i cant figure how to get the  border line equation of car.

update: i have made lines of border around the car, now i just need help with getting if these lines intersects with each other...
code is updated plz check it now...

one more thing, at this point there is only one line and i am going to add more lines in it... so i need a function to call it more often and get if the lines are intersecting with car border...

Note : use arrow keys to move car in snippet

Comment: only up is working

Comment: @abhinavxeon Press up and left/right at the same time

Comment: Try to define all the elements that can interact with eachother, eg the car, the line, other obstacles you'll add later, in the same way. So define the line with x,y width and height values as well. Then any collision becomes just comparing those.

Comment: You need a [2d rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) based on the car's angle, then multiply that with the vectors going from the car's center to the four corners. The image is 20x40, so the vector to the top left corner is (-10, -20). Multiply by the rotation matrix, then add the car's position to get the current canvas coordinate of the car's top left corner. Once you have the four corners in canvas coordinates, you can build the lines and intersect them with the track edges.

Comment: i have managed to add border around the car... now can anyone plz help me in getting the intersecting point of border lines with the other line.... plpzplzpzlpzl

Comment: Using translate to draw a box will not help you. I just wrote a lengthy comment telling you exactly what you need. Also, stackoverflow isn't a "please write this code for me" kind of website, you need to do tons of research and come up with your own attempt, then post a [mcve] that demonstrates a specific issue you have.